# Зачем убрали настройку прикрепления хедера?

Tags: поддержка

Раньше на сайте была возможность убрать пришпиливание хедера. Сейчас такой настройки нет. Хедер остаётся на месте при прокрутке вниз. Мне это не нужно, мешает пользоваться сайтом. Надоели танковые амбразуры на сайтах. Хочу пользоваться всем пространством монитора.

Как вернуть возможность отшпилить хедер?

Comment: Временный(?) фикс через браузерное расширение (любое из позволяющих применять пользовательские стили по условию URL страницы, [например это](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld)): `body { padding: 0 !important; } .top-bar { position: static !important; }`

Answer (score 4):

Очередное заминусованное нововведение от компании [We’ve removed the option to disable the fixed top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368973/339911) (из-за этого вопрос даже не видно на главной и надо заходить через список вопросов).

Вкратце, решено, что фичей пользуется очень малый процент посетителей и эта настройка привносит новые баги, с которыми не хочется возиться. Поэтому возможность настройки была отключена.

Comment: Странно, обычно всё наоборот — закреплённый хедер добавляет баги... Например [такие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/851746)